# Add PJSIP header on inbound channel

Tags: node.js, asterisk, pjsip, asterisk-ari

I am trying to add PJSIP header in asterisk in node.js but headers are not setting.

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    incoming.setChannelVar(
        {variable: 'PJSIP_HEADER(add,X-header)', value: '12423'},
        function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console_log(3, "SET-VAR ERROR", err);
            }
            resolve('done');
        }
    );
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log('Catch Error in executing setChanVar: ');
    });
```

As per Asterisk document we can only add PJSIP header on outbound channel
[Asterisk Wiki](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Function_PJSIP_HEADER)

Is there any alternate solution?

Comment: You can do that only on the outbound leg of the call. i.e before calling out using DIAL(PJSIP/...). It will work only for first INVITE of that call.

Comment: You should use Set Full Variable call. No idea how it looks in your library. Set Variable will not resolve/eval functions at all.

Comment: what is Set full variable call? how does it work?